# MongoDB PullFilter and UpdateMany C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have two collections: `sights` and `events`. They look like this:

```
//Sight document:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a14d93616016e2bb8796ccf"),
    "RelatedEventsId" : [
            ObjectId("5a14d93616016e2bb8796cd0"),
            ObjectId("5a14d93616016e2bb8796cd1")
    ]
    //other stuff
}

//Event document
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a14d93616016e2bb8796cd0"),
    "RelatedSightsId" : [
            ObjectId("5a14d93616016e2bb8796ccf")
    ]
    //other stuff
}
```

So, Sight and Event are related many-to-many. The problem I'm facing is to update the relations between particular documents. In method `EditSight` I want to update the sight in database by provided new-one. I have found the `idListToAdd` and `idListToDelete` for `RelatedEventsId` to add new relations and delete old one's in collection `events`.

```
var pull = Builders<Event>.Update.PullFilter(p => p.RelatedSightsId, f => f == oldSight.Id);
var push = Builders<Event>.Update.Push(p => p.RelatedSightsId, new ObjectId(id));

EventCol.UpdateMany<Event>(x => idListToDelete.Contains(x.Id), pull);
EventCol.UpdateMany<Event>(x => idListToAdd.Contains(x.Id), push);

SightCol.ReplaceOne(SBuilder.Eq(x => x.Id, new ObjectId(id)), newSight);
```

**pull** deletes old Ids in `event.RelatedSightsId` from `event` collection.

**push** adds new Ids into `event.RelatedSightsId` from `event` collection.

Also code above gives exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: {document} is not supported.
```

Also as extra it would be nice to do this update in bulk write.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in PullFilter, so I solved it like this:

```
List<Sight> sightsToPull = SightCol.Find(x => evnt.RelatedSightsId.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

foreach (Sight e in sightsToPull)
{
     foreach (var x in e.RelatedEventsId)
     {
        if (x == evnt.Id)
        {
             e.RelatedEventsId.Remove(x);
             break;
                    }
        }
     SightCol.ReplaceOne(x => x.Id == e.Id, e);
}
```

Lame, but at least works.